# Create differential signal from single ended encoder

Tags: differential, pulse, encoder, phototransistor

I have a problem with the output of an DC motor encoder feedback. I have an 5v single ended encoder (AB signal), but my control needs an differential signal. I am not sure how to do this as I have no experience working with "negative" voltages. I have multiple optocouplers based on the EL817 available and initially thought that I could just hookup a positive and a negative voltage to the output collector of the optocoupler, but I am not quite sure if the phototransistor would allow a negative voltage on the collector / have then a negative voltage on the emitter, as I am still kind of unclear how transistors handle negative voltage input. Can somebody enlighten me / help me out or has a good background site available about this transistor behaviour?
Also, what would happen if you put a negative input into a photocoupler (e.g. hook up a negative voltage source to the anode and put the cathode against mass)? In theory the LED should also only see a total 5v, right? Only important thing is the current limitation here as the led drop voltage is reached by the negative potential also? Or do I misunderstand LEDs completly?

Comment: Do you have to build this yourself? Single/differential encoders are standard CNC hardware. I bought some off Amazon for a few dollars and they work fine for motor control.

Comment: Describe in more detail what signal levels the control needs.

Comment: If I can buy a converter solution, I would be glad, but i did not find one yet. Deeper explanation: I had to swap all the electronics on a CNC mill I bought used, including the motors. Problem is the motors have a specialized mount and the only available replacement motors for this mount worldwide have only single-ended, not-interchangeable encoders. But the control I bought (separatly) need the encoder pulses in a +5v and -5v signal. Only thing I managed is to mod the drive that I get a very noisy + and - signal, but thats not enough for the control, so I thought can I do that directly?

Comment: Are you sure it is +/-5 (so 10v P-P) and not differential 5v (so 5v P-P)?  The latter is pretty standard:  https://www.cnc4pc.com/pub/media/productattachments/files/C72-R1.1_USER_MANUAL_VER.1.pdf

Comment: If I understand the P-P notation correctly, you mean the total signal difference, right? In that case, yes, its P-P 10v - for P-P 5v, that would only mean I have +5v on line A and 0v on line /A, which would not be acceptable to my drive/control. So I really need to get out +5v AND -5v pulses. The site you linked actually has such a product https://www.cnc4pc.com/differential-line-driver.html - so big thank you for that! Nevertheless to learn, how would one design this to get that result?

Comment: You may be overthinking this. What kind of "differential signal" does the control need? It may be that a single ended signal on IN+ and VCC/2 on IN- will do the job. Read the datasheet/manual carefully, and maybe link to it in the question.

Comment: The problem is that the datasheet/manual is wrong there. It states that single ended encoders are possible, albeit not recommended: https://www.copleycontrols.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Accelnet_Panel_CANopen-ADP-Datasheet-Datasheet.pdf But in reality, it sadly does not work. One of the engineers of the drive manufacturer is working here with me, but he is also surprised by this behaviour and does not have more ideas, so I try now to get at the problem from the other end.

Comment: Manual helps. The encoder port section says "26C32 differential line receiver". A well known part. So get the 26C32 chip datasheet; I think it'll confirm my earlier comment. (EDIT : should be OK if the encoder can drive that 121 ohm termination)

Comment: Thanks for the remark, but sadly, the theory says yes, but it still does not in reality. I am also unsure why, thats why I wanted to try to get a "proper" differential signal in as a countertest. So how would I design such a circuit? Is my optocoupler idea in the right ballpark?

Comment: This common task has single-chip solutions, like MC26LS30 or AM26LS30, if you can do the wiring.   Some units have configuration jumpers for alternate signals.

Comment: I look at the datasheet of the AM26LS30 (very useful hint, thanks) - how would that work internally? I mean, I feed only a positive voltage and have one gnd for the differential mode - how can I get out of that a same amplitude negative signal with BJTs? Would anybody so helpful as to make a short sketch / easycircuit example and explain?

Comment: You feed only a positive signal (0V/5V) ... the -ve leg must be biased to 2.5V so the differential voltage is +-2.5V, well above the +/-0.2V required (see datasheet).